# make background gradient smoother in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, gradient

I'm applying a linear background gradient to the `<html>` tag but in Firefox it's not very smooth, ie you can see lines: See this image:

[image]

In chrome it's much smoother. My CSS code is as follows:

```
html{
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#3c352e+0,121212+100 */
background: #3c352e; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #3c352e 0%, #121212 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3c352e), color-stop(100%,#121212)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #3c352e 0%,#121212 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #3c352e 0%,#121212 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #3c352e 0%,#121212 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #3c352e 0%,#121212 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3c352e', endColorstr='#121212',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
height:100vh;

}
```

Is there a way to smoothen this out?